# what can i say to my colleague when I get off work

Tags: spoken-english

when I am going to get off work. What could I say to my colleague who is still working and ask why he haven't get off work.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Saluton. I'm not entirely clear what you're asking, here. Could you explain the scenario in more detail? It's best if you edit your question to include those extra details.

Comment: In particular if you want to ask why he hasn't got off work, why can't you say "Why haven't you got off work?"